# how read and delete line by line from a text file using java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, printwriter

I have a text file that contains 2 line likes

- Hello World 1.
- Hello World 2.

I want to read and delete those 2 line one by one. Successfully i read those 2 line but when i deleting those then it fails. This is my code.

```
@FXML
public void buttonLineDeleteAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    try {
        String line = null;
        final File fileGpNumber = new File(filePath);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileGpNumber);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println("Line--- " + line);
            boolean result = removeLineFromFile(line);
            System.out.println("Result---> " + result);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException " + e);
    }
}
```

And remove line bye this method.

```
private boolean removeLineFromFile(String lineToRemove) {
    boolean isDeleted = false;
    try {
        File inFile = new File(filePath);
        File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
        String line;

        //Read from the original file and write to the new 
        //unless content matches data to be removed.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {
                pw.println(line);
                pw.flush();
                isDeleted = false;
            } else {
                isDeleted = true;
            }
        }
        pw.close();
        br.close();

        //Delete the original file
        if (inFile.delete()) {
            isDeleted = true;
        } else {
            isDeleted = false;
            System.out.println("Could not delete file.");
        }
        //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
        if (tempFile.renameTo(inFile)) {
          isDeleted = true;
        } else {
         System.out.println("Could not rename file.");
         isDeleted = false;
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return isDeleted;
}
```

Now deleting those line in my tempFile but problem in deleting the inFile and rename thetempFile file.
This is my output

```
Line--- Hello World 1.
Could not delete file.
Could not rename file.
Result---> false
Line--- Hello World 2.
Could not delete file.
Could not rename file.
Result---> false
```

Please Help me anyone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't delete the first file in your `removeLineFromFile` because it is still locked by your `buttonLineDeleteAction` method (as you are in the middle of reading the file content and you didn't `close` the file reader objects).

So, you need to follow the below steps:

(1) Find out all the required lines and collect them into a List and **close the file**

(2) Create a new file and write the contents from List and **close the file**

(3) Delete the old file now

(4) Rename the new file and close the new file